# How to change react-dates input border color?

Tags: reactjs, react-dates

How can I change `react-dates` input border color depending on a component state?

I want to set the input border to red when there is an error on my form and the normal color when everything is ok.

I'm looking for this but I can't find it.

I'm in version `20.2.0`

## Edit:

I want to do something like this

```
<SingleDatePicker
    {...otherProps}
    styles={{border: '1px solid red'}}
/>
```

But I can't do that because `react-dates` don't provide a `styles` or `className` prop. Also, overriding the css don't work, because I need to togle the style, not just change it once.

Comment: This is not enough. Add some code, show your effort

Comment: I can't add code or show effort. `react-dates` don't provide a `styles` or `className` prop, so I have no idea on how to change the style depending on a variable

Answer (score 4):

Override the CSS:

```
.error .SingleDatePicker .DateInput_input {
  border: 1px solid #bf2155;
}
```

Use a div around the component with a validation state:

```
<div className={this.props.value ? null : 'error'}>
  <SingleDatePicker/>
</div>
```

Comment: This was a life-saver. I was looking to change border of DatePicker from many hours. However, for me the reverse of above worked. <div className={props.errors.myValue && props.touched.myValue ? 'my-value-error-class' : null}>

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Nate's answer,

I did need to change different `react-datepicker` class than @nate stated in order to get the border to change on errors/no-input.

May be related to `react` & `react-datepicker` & `formic` packager version (listed below).

```
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-datepicker": "^3.3.0",
"react-dom": "^17.0.1",
"react-formik-ui": "^5.0.2",
```

**CSS Override**

```
.picker-error .react-datepicker__input-container input {
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
```

**Component Override**

```
<div className={props.errors.startDate && props.touched.startDate ? 'picker-error' : null}>
<DatePicker
 ....
 ....
>
</div>
```